# Proper way to align FromDate and ToDate?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Large Screen
[image: Large Screen]

Medium Screen
[image: Medium Screen]

Expected Result in Medium Screen
[image: Expected Result when Medium Screen]

Hi, I am new to bootstrap and css. I wish to make from date and to date align properly when it is medium size screen. I somehow did it, but I don't think it is a proper way. Here is my code:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
                @Html.Label("From Date: ")

                @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                 .Culture("en-GB")
                .Name("selectedFromDate")
                .Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
                .Value(DateTime.Now)
                )
                <label id="ErrorMsgFromDate" style="color:red;"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
                @Html.Label("To Date: ")
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                 .Culture("en-GB")
                .Name("selectedToDate")
                .Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
                .Value(DateTime.Now)
                )

                <label id="ErrorMsgToDate" style="color:red;"></label>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div><br /></div>

        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="btnSearch" class="btn" style="font-weight:bold"/>
```

Comment: Bootstraps grid system uses 12 columns, so `col-xs-9` would result in a linebreak, as 2 * 9 is 18 which more than 12.

Comment: But when the screen is small. It become like this.[https://imgur.com/nFu7XXc]

Comment: How about adding custom css for the label and datepicker? To make it more generic you can add a generic class name for the parent div, so that the element is identified as datepicker element.

Comment: @VinayGayakwad Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: If you can create a demo in fiddle, I can give a try to show it with code changes